Coq : transitivity fails on list intermediate term
I'm doing this exercises from LF:
Example injection_ex3 : ∀ (X : Type) (x y z : X) (l j : list X),
  x :: y :: l = z :: j →
  j = z :: l →
  x = y.

My question is that why transitivity fails here:
Proof.
  intros X x y z l j H I. 
  injection H as J.
  Fail transitivity j. (* shouldn't fail imho *) 

The environment at this point:
1 subgoal

X : Type
x, y, z : X
l, j : list X
J : x = z
H : y :: l = j
I : j = z :: l

========================= (1 / 1)

x = y

And the error is :
The command has indeed failed with message:
In environment
X : Type
x, y, z : X
l, j : list X
J : x = z
H : y :: l = j
I : j = z :: l
The term "j" has type "list X" while it is expected to have type "X".  

It seems quite straightforward here that j is the intermediate term and it should be "list X".
What was wrong?

Your goal is an equality between terms of type X, so in order to use transitivity to prove the goal you must provide an intermediate term of type X. It seems like you want to use transitivity to prove y :: l = z :: l, so you must introduce that as an intermediate goal.

I see, thanks. It wasn't obvious when first learning to use transitivity. Now it makes more sense that the tactics are aiming at the goal, not just infer information from the environment. The book doesn't state this and I somehow just assumed and skipped that middle step. @NaïmFavier

I think this is a useful information which could help others. You can write that as an answer if you wish, and I will accept it. Thanks for the help! @NaïmFavier

transitivity j. fails because that means you want to say that x = j  which are of  different types, x : X and j : list X

I got some misunderstandings from earlier exercises trans_eq_example'' and trans_eq_exercise, after read your comment I reviewed and reflected, it makes more sense now. Thanks! @larsr
